# Twilio + Express Multer

Tags: node.js, express, twilio, content-type, multer

I'm trying to make a web app that sends MMS using the Twilio API. Uploading an image from my local machine works perfectly. I'm using [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) to save the image.

After saving the image using multer I want to send it via MMS using Twilio but I keep getting this error in the twilio monitor
**Error: 12300 - Invalid Content-Type**

This is my form:

```
<form method="post" encType="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
    <input type="file" name="imageFile" />
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

My server.js:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '/uploads');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}.png`);
    }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/upload', upload.single('imageFile'), function (req, res, next) {
    var user = ref.getAuth();
    var file = req.file.filename;
    client.messages.create({
        from: twilioNumber,
        to: 1234567890,
        mediaContentType: 'image/png',
        mediaUrl: `http://example.com/uploads/${file}`
    }, function(err, message) {
       if(err) {
          console.log('Error!', err);
       } else {
          console.log('Message SID:', message.sid);
       }
   }
});
```

As you can see I'm including the Content-Type inside `client.messages.create`. I also wished I don't get redirected to `/upload` route every time I upload an image.

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  What Twilio is saying in that error message is that the HTTP response its getting from the mediaURL you've provided has a Content-Type header value that we don't understand.  If you curl that URL what is the Content-Type header value that is returned?

Comment: @DevinRader I'm getting text/html. Shouldn't it be `image/png` since I manually set it in `mediaContentType`?

Comment: You would have to configure whatever server and/or application framework you are using to serve the url "http://example.com/uploads/${file}" to serve that URL with the appropriate Content-Type header.  As far as I know mediaContentType is not a parameter twilio will recognize when using the create function to have Twilio send an MMS.

This is why I suggested using curl to request that URL  If the curl request does not show the right content type, twilio won't get it either.

Comment: @DevinRader how can I do that? I'm a newbie with this.

Comment: that depends on how you're serving the file.  Is ${file} jus a static file on disk somewhere?

Comment: I fixed it yesterday! I didnt need "uploads" in the link because I was serving it as a static file lol. Thank you :)

Comment: Hey corasan, happy to hear you got it fixed! Would you post your updated code in an answer so people who land here in the future can skip the fine print in comments?